# If a branch of an iteration tree drops in model or degree, the last model won't be $\omega$-sound

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, set-theory

I am studying about iteration trees from the "An Outline of Inner Model Theory" article in the handbook and I'm struggling with a certain type of an argument which appears in both the proof of the comparison lemma and the following paragraph after it. It's on page $1620$. Since the proof of the comparison lemma is a bit long, I will omit most of it to have a shorter post and write more about my own thinking on it.

So let $M$ and $N$ be $k$-sound premice of size $\le \theta$, and suppose $\Sigma$ and $\Gamma$ are $(k, \theta^++1)$-iteration strategies for $M$ and $N$ respectively; then we recursively build iteration trees $T_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha$ played according to $\Sigma$ and $\Gamma$ by "iterating away the least disagreement". And at this stage of the proof assume that $\alpha < \theta^+$ is such that the last models of $T_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha$ are comparable and call them $M^T_\beta$ and $M^U_\gamma$.

Now my problem is with the assertion in the last part of the proof, where if we take $M_\beta^T = M_\gamma^U$ and let $n = \deg^T(\beta) = \deg^U(\gamma)$ be the largest $n$ where $M_\beta^T$ is $n$-sound, if we assume both of their branches either drop in model or degree, then there exists $\xi+1 \in [0, \beta]_T$ and $\eta+1 \in [0, \gamma]_U$ such that: $$i^T_{\xi+1,\beta}\circ i^{*T}_{\xi+1}  = \text{ uncollapse map from } C_{n+1}(M_\beta^T) \text{ to } C_n(M_\beta^T)\\ = \text{ uncollapse map from } C_{n+1}(M_\gamma^U) \text{ to } C_n(M_\gamma^U)\\ = i^U_{\eta+1,\gamma}\circ i^{*U}_{\eta+1}.$$

Clearly by symmetry we need only find $\xi+1$; so we will only work with objects related to $T$ and drop the superscripts. First, note that if $\beta$ is itself a limit ordinal, then by the conditions on a well-founded branch, $D\cap [0, \beta]$ is bounded; and also we know that $\deg(\alpha+1)$ below $\beta$ must be eventually constant, so let $\xi+1 < \beta$ be such that $\deg(\xi+1) = \deg(\beta)$ and that $D\cap (\alpha+1, \beta] = \emptyset$, then by theorem $3.8$ we may see that $\xi+1$ is as desired.

Now my problem is with the case that $\beta = \alpha+1$. In this case, I can find $\xi+1$ only when $n$ is finite. In this case, let $\zeta = \text{pred}(\beta)$. First assume that $\beta = \alpha+1 \in D$, in that case $M^*_{\alpha+1}$ is a proper initial segment of $M_\zeta$ and so is $\omega$-sound. Also if we let $\kappa$ be the critical point of the extender used to construct $M_\beta$, then by the construction of iteration trees we must have $\rho_{n+1}(M^*_{\alpha+1}) \le \kappa < \rho_n(M^*_{\alpha+1})$ and since $M^*_{\alpha+1}$ is $\omega$-sound, by lemma $2.23$, the map $i^*_{\alpha+1}$ is the uncollapse map from $C_{n+1}(M_\beta) \text{ to } C_n(M_\beta)$ and we can take $\xi+1 = \alpha+1$.

Now if $\beta \not \in D$, we have again two cases, if we have $\deg(\text{pred}(\beta)) > \deg(\beta)$, by a similar argument to the case $\beta \in D$, we can take $\xi+1 = \beta$, so also assume $\deg(\text{pred}(\beta)) = \deg(\beta)$. But now if $\text{pred}(\beta)$ is a successor ordinal, we are done by theorem $3.8$ and we may take $\xi+1 = \text{pred}(\beta)$. And if $\text{pred}(\beta)$ is a limit ordinal, since the elements of $D$ are bounded below it, pick the largest ordinal $\xi+1$ below $\text{pred}(\beta)$, where the $\deg$ function stabilizes and also $D\cap(\xi+1, \beta] = \emptyset$, then we again are done by theorem $3.8$.

But I don't know what to do when $n = \omega$. Because then, I can't use the inequality $\rho_{n+1}(M^*_{\alpha+1}) \le \kappa < \rho_n(M^*_{\alpha+1})$, in the case that $\beta = \alpha+1 \in D$. And my proof falls short. What can we say about this case? (to be more precise: when $\beta$ is a successor and $n = \omega$.)

I feel that my above argument works, but I would appreciate any remarks or hints at it's potential flaws. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Because we are assuming there is a drop in model or degree along $[0,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}$, we have $n=\mathrm{deg}^{\mathcal{T}}(\beta)<\omega$, i.e. the largest integer $m$ such that $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta$ is $m$-sound, is ${\mathrm{deg}^{\mathcal{T}}(\beta)<\omega}$. (Also, I'm not sure you got the right $\xi+1$ in some cases above. We always want the least ordinal $\xi+1\leq_{\mathcal{T}}\beta$ such that $(\xi+1,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}\cap D=\emptyset$ and $\mathrm{deg}^{\mathcal{T}}(\xi+1)=\mathrm{deg}^{\mathcal{T}}(\beta)=n$...

Comment: ...equivalently, the last drop in model or degree along $[0,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}$ occurs at $\xi+1$.)

Comment: @FarmerS, Well, our $\xi+1$ should be such that $D\cap (\xi+1, \beta]$ is empty right? So we shouldn't drop in model after $\xi+1$, so I think we should take the largest $\xi+1$ where we drop in model or degree. In the cases above, I have tried to take $\xi+1$ like that. But where the argument breaks down, is where $\beta$ is a successor, and we exactly drop in model at the construction of $M_\beta$, how can we say that we also drop in degree there, as you mentioned?

Comment: Also, you mentioned we must take the least such $\xi+1$, but by theorem $3.8$, any $\zeta+1$, such that $\xi+1 T\zeta+1 T \beta$ also works because it inherits the properties of $\xi+1$, no?

Comment: Remark: it might be just a typo in your question/comment, but it should be $(\xi+1,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}$, not $(\xi+1,\beta]$, as $(\xi+1,\beta]$ is just the usual ordinal interval, whereas $(\xi+1,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}$ is the tree interval, and we might have $D\cap(\xi+1,\beta]\neq\emptyset$, while $D\cap(\xi+1,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}=\emptyset$.

Comment: @FarmerS, yes you are absolutely correct, I dropped the subscript for $T$. I also did that in my reasoning above and all my intervals are in the tree order.

Comment: Okay, so, right, we want $D\cap(\xi+1,\beta]_{\mathcal{T}}=\emptyset$, and in fact we want the largest drop in model or degree at $\xi+1$. (I won't assume $\xi+1=\beta$, but it could be.) If $\mathcal{T}$ drops in model at $\xi+1$, then we have $N=M^{*\mathcal{T}}_{\xi+1}\triangleleft M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta$ (here $\triangleleft$ meaning "is a proper segment of")...

Comment: ...and $\mathrm{deg}^{\mathcal{T}}(\beta)$ is the least $m$ such that $\rho_{m+1}^N\leq\kappa<\rho_m^N$ where $\kappa=\mathrm{crit}(E^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$. Here $m<\omega$ exists like this because $\rho_{\omega}^N\leq\kappa$ and $\rho_\omega^N=\lim_{i<\omega}\rho_i^N$ (as there was a drop in model). (Note these circumstances are using the fact that $\mathcal{T}$ is $k$-maximal. One should also note that $\kappa<\rho_0^N$ does hold.) But then it works just like you mentioned in your question when there is just a drop in degree.

Comment: If we now take some $\zeta$ such that $\xi+1<_{\mathcal{T}}\zeta+1\leq_{\mathcal{T}}\beta$ then $i^{\mathcal{T}}_{\xi+1,\beta}\circ i^{*\mathcal{T}}_{\xi+1}\neq i^{\mathcal{T}}_{\zeta+1,\beta}\circ i^{*\mathcal{T}}_{\zeta+1}$ (e.g. they have different critical points, as the first starts with $E^{\mathcal{T}}_{\xi}$, but the second with $E^{\mathcal{T}}_{\zeta}$). Therefore they can't both be the uncollapse map from $\mathfrak{C}_{n+1}(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$ into $\mathfrak{C}_n(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$, as this map depends only on $M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta$.

Comment: @FarmerS, I am confused now. Because what you say seems quite true, but on the other hand if $\xi+1$ satisfies the requirements of theorem $3.8$ including the "moreover" part, then it seems to me that any $\zeta+1$ such that $\xi+1 T\zeta+1 T\beta$, must satisfy them as well; and we should get the uncollapse maps from both of them.

Comment: But Theorem 3.8 doesn't include the statement that $i^{\mathcal{T}}_{\xi+1,\beta}\circ i^{*\mathcal{T}}_{\xi+1} = $ the core embedding $\mathfrak{C}_{n+1}(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)\to\mathfrak{C}_n(M^{\mathcal{T}}_\beta)$ (which I was assuming you meant by the uncollapse map between these in your question). (By Theorem 3.8 we do get that $M^{\mathcal{T}}_{\xi+1}$ and $M^{\mathcal{T}}_{\zeta+1}$ will have the same $(n+1)$th core.)

Comment: @FarmerS, Oh you are right. Then I think part of my fundamental problem is with the discussion following theorem $3.8$. To be more precise, I both don't know $(I)$ why there $\zeta+1$ can't work, also another thing I spotted now is that $(II)$ there, it is assumed that (in the notation of that part) $M^*_{\alpha+1}$ is $(n+1)$-sound and $\deg(\alpha) = n$, isn't this contradictory with the fact that $\deg(\alpha)$ is largest such that $M^*_{\alpha+1}$ is $\deg(\alpha)$-sound?

Comment: Re the paragraph following proof of Theorem 3.8: First note, just in case of confusion, the $\alpha$ in the 2nd-last sentence (i.e. "We then have that...") should not be identified with the $\alpha$ in the last sentence (i.e. "If $M^*_{\alpha+1}$..."); instead the $\beta$ in the last sentence is like the $\alpha$ in the second-to-last.

Comment: Second, in the last sentence of that paragraph, we have $\mathrm{deg}(\alpha+1)=n$, not $\mathrm{deg}(\alpha)=n$ (it doesn't matter what $\mathrm{deg}(\alpha)$ is). So, $n=\mathrm{deg}(\beta)=\mathrm{deg}(\alpha+1)$ is largest such that $M_\beta$ is $n$-sound, and is largest such that $M_{\alpha+1}$ is $n$-sound. But $M^*_{\alpha+1}$ (the "ultrapower preimage" of $M_{\alpha+1}$) is $(n+1)$-sound. There was a drop in model or degree at $\alpha+1$, and $\alpha+1$ is the largest such ordinal along the branch leading to $\beta$. (So $\alpha+1=\xi+1$ from our earlier notation.)

Comment: "Ultrapower preimage" as in $M_{\alpha+1}=\mathrm{Ult}_n(M^*_{\alpha+1},E^{\mathcal{T}}_\alpha)$.

Comment: @FarmerS, Oh I see. Thanks for clearing things up; I really appreciate it. I now understand your reasoning. So to sum things up, I now understand why we need to take the least such $\xi+1$. Now I think the only missing puzzle piece for my question is to understand why $\rho_\omega^N \le \kappa$ in your $5$th comment. Why does that happen? Is it because in finding the initial segment $N = M^*_{\xi+1}$ of $M_{\text{pred}(\xi+1)}$, if $\rho_\omega^N > \kappa$, we can still enlarge $M^*_{\xi+1}$ and still have $E_\xi$ be an extender over it and this would contradict our tree construction choice?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Because $\mathcal{T}$ is taken to be $k$-maximal, we take the largest possible $N$ and degree that the extender can handle, which implies that if there is a drop in model to $N=M^*_{\xi+1}$, we must have $\rho_\omega^N\leq\kappa$, as otherwise, as you say, we could have taken a larger segment instead of $N$.

Comment: @FarmerS, Oh I see. Thanks for the help; I actually can't stress enough on how much this discussion was enlightening. Also since this discussion fully resolves my question I would happily accept it as an answer if you choose to post it.